# Is there a way to have fewer polygons in the viewport temporarily or maybe only in viewport but after render it remains the same?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

Just like, in the viewport there would be a lot fewer polygons but when you go in render it would show the original way the polygons of the model were just to save up your computer resources so you face less lag.

Answer (score 1):

STEP 1
**select your mesh , go to properties tab and to the modifiers properties(the wrench).**

[image]

STEP 2
**click add modifier and in the drop down select decimate.**

[image]

STEP 3
**Go to unsubdivide option and increase the iterations and as expected it will unsuubdivide your mesh.**
[image]

STEP 4
**to disable it in your renders select the camera so that an 'X' mark appears in the middle**.

[image]

***and now your mesh should be unsubdivided temporarily in your viewport but not in the render***
[image]